# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument, running Django on a shared hosting

Tags: python, django, cgi, shared-hosting

I'm migrating my web to another server, and I'm setting up everything for django the work.
I could solve lots of problems but this one beat me. I have no idea what can cause it.

This is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usuario/public_html/cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi", line 24, in <module>
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
  File "/home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py", line 182, in runfastcgi
    WSGIServer(get_internal_wsgi_application(), **wsgi_opts).run()
  File "/home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi.py", line 114, in run
    ret = ThreadedServer.run(self, sock)
  File "/home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flup/server/threadedserver.py", line 85, in run
    clientSock, addr = sock.accept()
  File "/home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 184, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

.htaccess:

```
AddHandler dispatch.cgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/dispatch.cgi/$1 [L]
```

dispatch.cgi:

```
#!/home/usuario/test/bin/python3.4m
import sys, os
import traceback

sys.path += ['/home/usuario/app-test']
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/home/usuario/test/lib'

#Switch to new python
PYTHON_EXE = '/home/usuario/test/bin/python3.4'

sys.path.insert(0,'home/usuario/test/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flup')
sys.path.insert(0,'home/usuario/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "app.settings"

try:
    from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
except:
    traceback.print_exc(file=open('/home/usuario/public_html/log.txt','w'))
```

It's important to point out I dont have ssh access on the server, so if anyone comes up with a solution it would have to be without the need of ssh.
Is it a configuration problem ? Or is it server sided ? And if it is, is there a workaround ?

I use python 3.4 and Django 1.6.5

Comment: What version of Django are you using here? It hasn't supported fastcgi for ages. If you really can't use wsgi on your server, you should probably find a different host. There are plenty of cheap ones nowadays.

Comment: I edited it, I got it working on godaddy, this server has the same structure as godaddy, so I should be able to get it to work